# Testar conteúdo de variável

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Usando ASP.Net MVC e AngularJS testei o conteúdo de um campo da *view* assim:

```
$scope.estado.ldRedeBasica =  @(Model.ldRedeBasica == null ? "[]" : Html.Raw(Model.ldRedeBasica));
```

Só que retornou o seguinte erro:

> Mensagem de Erro do Compilador: CS0173: O tipo de expressão condicional não pode ser determinado porque não há conversão implícita
>   entre 'string' e 'System.Web.IHtmlString'

O interessante é que em outra parte do código funciona:

```
$scope.ViewBag.Impostos = @(ViewBag.Impostos == null ? "[]" : Html.Raw(ViewBag.Impostos));
```

Com contornar este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
$scope.estado.ldRedeBasica =  @(Model.ldRedeBasica == null
                                ? new MvcHtmlString("[]") // ou poderia ser `Html.Raw("[]")`
                                : Html.Raw(Model.ldRedeBasica));
```

<sup>[Documentação do MvcHtmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.mvchtmlstring%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)</sup>

O erro ocorre pois `Html.Raw` não retorna `string`, mas sim uma implementação do tipo `IHtmlString`.

Imagine a situação:

```
var x = (condicao == true) ? "string" : 32784;
```

Qual seria o tipo de `x`?... impossível dizer. O erro que você tem é do mesmo tipo do erro acima.

Para ser possível determinar o tipo de uma condição usando operador ternário, é necessário que uma das expressões seja conversível para o tipo da outra expressão... que não é o caso.

- nem de `string` para `IHtmlString`
- nem de `IHtmlString` para `string`

Agora, para saber o motivo do outro código funcionar, ai será necessária uma investigação mais profunda... não sendo possível dizer só com o que foi posto.

Comment: Agradeço a resposta! Realmente não retornou o erro original. Agora esta retornando _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;_ no console o código esta assim: `$scope.estado.ldRedeBasica =  ;`.

Comment: De que tipo é `Model.ldRedeBasica`?

Comment: Se for um array ou lista, você deverá serializar o objeto para JSON antes de usar `Html.Raw` nela.

Comment: Resolvi assim: `$scope.estado.ldRedeBasica =  @(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ldRedeBasica) ? Html.Raw("[]") : Html.Raw(Model.ldRedeBasica));`. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Pelo que disse, dá para ver que o tipo é string. Use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` ao invés disso, para descartar também a possibilidade de espaços em branco.

Comment: Foi mal é String mesmo! Vou fazer a alteração. Mais uma vez obrigado!